# click handler with dojo editor

Tags: javascript, dojo, click

i have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head> 
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js"
    type="text/javascript" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myButton = dojo.byId("btn");
dojo.connect(myButton, "onclick", function (evt) {
    require(["dojo/_base/xhr", "dojo/parser", "dojo/dom"], function (xhr, parser, dom) {
        xhr.get({
            url: "teste_apagar.php",
            load: function (data) {
                alert("as");
                var um = [];
                dijit.registry.filter(function(w){ 
                   if(dojo.indexOf(um)){
                        w.destroyRecursive();
                   }
                });
                dom.byId("result").innerHTML = data;
                parser.parse("result");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body class="claro">
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.require("dijit.Editor");
</script>

<div id="btn" style="width: 100px; height: 30px; margin-bottom: 150px; background-color: red;">load</div>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when i click in bold button, or italic, even with right click in top bar with the formatting options, the ajax request is reloaded. So the dojo editor is loaded when i press the formatting toolbar

Any idea ? **demo** [here](http://jsbin.com/ukesup/2/edit#preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute Dojo code once Dojo is loaded. See http://jsbin.com/ukesup/7.

In the way you are doing the 'myButton' is null beacuse dojo isn't loaded yet and dojo.byId returns invalid value or simply doesn't exist.

Also remember to load required widgets once dojo is loaded. In the sample i used the Dojo <1.7 way:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {  
    dojo.require("dijit.Editor");
    ...
    more code here
    ...
});
```